# java datechooser how to get date

Tags: java, getdate, datechooser

```
        DateFormat dateformatYYYYMMDD = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    String nowYYYYMMDD = new String( dateformatYYYYMMDD.format( dateChooser.getDate()) );
    textField_1.setText(nowYYYYMMDD);
```

i tried this way but i cant get date from datechooser
error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1032)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:785)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:778)
at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:314)
at Remontas.jbInit(Remontas.java:239)
at Remontas.<init>(Remontas.java:176)
at Remontas.main(Remontas.java:161)
```

Comment: where does datechooser came from ?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `dateChooser.getDate()` is returning null, given the stack trace. We can't tell why that is from the code you've given us.

Note that you're calling this from your `Remontas` *constructor* - is that deliberate?

Answer (score 0):

use this code, it worked for me
ps.setString(1, ((JTextField)txtDate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());